# Are there other cooperative world building games like Dawn of Worlds?

Tags: campaign-development, tools

I found Dawn of Worlds on the web and got the [PDF](http://www.clanwebsite.org/games/rpg/Dawn_of_Worlds_game_1_0Final.pdf) of it.  My group tried and loved it. I was wondering has anyone else worked with this very novel system for cooperative world building?

Comment: Hey @Ace! IMHO, your first question is way too broad. What specifically are you interested in? Your second question is a good one that, with some more details, could stand on its own: "Are there systems similar to DoW in how it does X and Y?".

Comment: The link links back to this question. Could someone correct the link?

Comment: Link corrected. Not sure who added it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at **[Microscope](http://www.lamemage.com/blog/index.php/category/microscope/)**. It just finished its playtest cycle and should be out soonish. The game is all about starting at the macro level and slowly zooming in on details of particular portions of the world.

It's likely inspired by **ARIA: Canticle of the Monomyth**, way out of print. The *Worlds* book specifically addresses shared creation of the setting. Your best bet in finding one is eBay.

Comment: +1! Microscope is excellent for building a setting, especially the way the game focuses on answering questions you have about the details you're building. A normal game generates a compelling setting, but by having world-building explicitly in mind the questions and answers would be even better honed for creating a nuanced setting.

Comment: FYI [Microscope was just released at IPR](http://www.indiepressrevolution.com/xcart/product.php?productid=17541) as a PDF; print is on the way.

Answer (score 4):

An answer to the question in the title would be [Universalis](http://ramshead.indie-rpgs.com/) from Ramshead Publishing. Part of play in Universalis involves taking turns making assertions about the game world and campaign to follow, and there's a "stakes" mechanism involved in enforcing those desires.

Answer (score 0):

Another system that would deliver this is [Shock: Social Science Fiction](http://glyphpress.com/shock/) (and presumably Human Contact to a degree).